# Depth buffer does not work on Android, but does work on Linux (using Kivy)

Tags: android, python, opengl, opengl-es, kivy

I wrote a simple example of this problem.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
import random

class Root(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *larg, **kw):
        super(Root, self).__init__(*larg, **kw)
        self.vertices = [[-1,-1, 0,    1,-1, 0,    1, 1, 0,   -1, 1, 0]]
        kw['shader_file'] = 'shaders.glsl'
        self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
        shader_file = kw.pop('shader_file')
        self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find(shader_file)
        with self.canvas:
            self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
            PushMatrix()
            Translate(0, 0, -5)
            for i in xrange(10):
                Translate(.5, 0, -.5)
                self.render(self.vertices, (random.random(), random.random(), random.random()))
            PopMatrix()
            self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)
        asp = float(Window.width) / Window.height / 2.0
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 100, 1)
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj

    def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def render(self, vertices, color):
        for i in xrange(len(vertices)):
            ChangeState(Kd=color, Ka=color, Ks=(.3, .3, .3), Tr=1., Ns=1., intensity=1.)
            Mesh(vertices=vertices[i], indices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2], fmt=[('v_pos', 3, 'float')], mode='triangles')

class TestApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Note: I used [this](https://github.com/nskrypnik/kivy-rubik/blob/master/shaders.glsl) `shaders.glsl`.

It renders 10 squares, which have same dimensions, but random colors. Every new square is relatively translated by `Translate(.5, 0, -.5)`, so the last rendered one is the furthest one.
Since there is `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, when I run this **on Linux, it is rendered correctly:**
[image]

But after I had created *.apk using Buildozer (in `buildzer.spec` I only changed `title`, `name`, `version` and added `glsl` to `include_exts`) and ran it **on Android (4.4), it was rendered uncorrectly** (like if `GL_DEPTH_TEST` was disabled):
[image]

The problem might be the difference between OpenGL ES and OpengGL, but I think, that `GL_DEPTH_TEST` should work on both. Also there might be a problem with packaging, but it does not seem like it.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific framework. But with any other framework I have seen, there are normally attributes/settings somewhere during initialization where you specify that you need a depth buffer. This is normally somewhere around where the context and rendering surface are created. You may want to check the documentation for the framework, and see if you can find something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Reto Koradi had suggested, I looked again even deeper into the Kivy documentation. I discovered Framebuffer (module `kivy.graphics.fbo`), which is an offscreen window, that acts like a Kivy Canvas. It (probably unlike Canvas) has `with_depthbuffer` parameter, which is set to `False` by default.

So the solution was to set `with_depthbuffer = True` in Framebuffer and then use the Framebuffer's rendered texture in Canvas in order to display it.

I am not sure why this is necessary for Android, but not for Linux. There also might be a better option, which does not include creating (sometimes meaningless) Framebuffer, but this method at least works on both platforms.

I modified the example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.resources import resource_find
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics.opengl import *
import random

class Root(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *larg, **kw):
        super(Root, self).__init__(*larg, **kw)     
        self.vertices = [[-1,-1, 0,    1,-1, 0,    1, 1, 0,   -1, 1, 0]]
        with self.canvas:
             self.fbo = Fbo(with_depthbuffer = True, size = Window.size)
             Rectangle(size=Window.size, texture=self.fbo.texture)

        kw['shader_file'] = 'shaders.glsl'
        shader_file = kw.pop('shader_file')   
        self.fbo.shader.source = resource_find(shader_file)
        with self.fbo:
            self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
            PushMatrix()
            Translate(0, 0, -5)
            for i in xrange(10):
                Translate(.5, 0, -.5)
                self.render(self.vertices, (random.random(), random.random(), random.random()))
            PopMatrix()
            self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)

        asp = float(Window.width) / Window.height / 2.0
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 100, 1)
        self.fbo['projection_mat'] = proj

    def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def render(self, vertices, color):
        for i in xrange(len(vertices)):
            ChangeState(Kd=color, Ka=color, Ks=(.3, .3, .3), Tr=1., Ns=1., intensity=1.)
            Mesh(vertices=vertices[i], indices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2], fmt=[('v_pos', 3, 'float')], mode='triangles')

class TestApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Again without knowledge of the specific framework, I would expect there to be an option to request a depth buffer for the default framebuffer as well. But it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: I would expect that too, but so far I have not been able to find such an option. If I discover it, I will update my answer. Anyway, thank you for advising me.